# How to enable Ios Callkit Call Directory extension

Tags: ios, react-native, callkit, call-directory-extension

I am trying to add the Callkit Call Directory extension to my React Native app so that I can add additional numbers that will show with caller id (populated from my app).

The Callkit documentation states:

*"Before a Call Directory extension can operate on incoming calls, the user must explicitly enable the extension in the iOS Settings app."*

However, there is no section for "Call blocking and identification" in my phone's settings (see here for similar issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251896172)

I have tried using the `openSettingsWithCompletionHandler` method, which does open the settings on the phone, but still no option for "Call blocking and identification".

How can I let my app use this functionality if it cannot be seen in the phone settings? Am I doing something completely backward?

Thanks.

Comment: That setting only appears if an app containing a call kit blocking or call identification extension is installed.  It is likely that the build of your app that you have installed does not contain your extension

Comment: I have added a Call Directory extension, and I am able to call the `getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier` method. Is there some way to verify if the extension is installed properly?

Comment: could it be when you run it, you run your app independently without your extension?